# A comparison between the differentiable manifolds definitions along books

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, analytic-geometry

I'm studying differential geometry to have a good writing in a paper and contextualizing the reader about this topic in Applied Mathematics context. In this context, I'm applying the [**Theorem 2.1**](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-317-02/S0002-9947-1990-0943608-5/) to some optimization problems with analytic constraints. Basically, the context of manifold I'm using is in the finite-dimensional, Hausdorff, second countable manifold of pure dimension (i.e. such that all the connected components have the same dimension). All my manifolds considered is of class $C^{\omega}$, i.e. real analytic. Here, my concern is with clarity to the reader, which is not really fluent with this tool. For example, seems hard to me to understand and grasp the differences between several differentiable manifolds definitions, and which one I should state for the reader.

As an example, the Varadarajan's book says that a manifold is a pair $(M,\mathfrak{D})$ satisfying the following:

[image].

While on book Narasimhan's Book I found a simpler one without introducing a differentiable structure:

[image]

But there is another third and more geometric one I have found on Munkres's book:

[image]

My question is:

> Is all these definitions equivalent when translated correctly? What are the differences? Which one I should state for the reader first?

Comment: Munkres is working only with submanifolds of $\Bbb R^n$. The other two are defining a manifold structure on a topological space. The first is quite non-standard, and the second is the standard one.

Comment: Is the Munkres's definition equivalent to the standart in his context?

Comment: I need to know If I am treating of the same object mainly, at least in the same context. Looking the defintions, they look different. For example, the standart definition seems to be cosidering more objects to be differentiable manifolds than the one that Munkres have said. For example, the only chart $(\mathbb{R}^{n}, (x,y) \mapsto (x,y, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}))$ seems to be an atlas, but not an "atlas" in Munkres's definition.

Comment: Yes, I said that in my first sentence. You should edit your post to include the context in which you need to work with smooth manifolds.

Comment: I updated my question. It seems more readable and understandable I think. Hope you undestand it. 

But again, is the Munkres's definition equivalent to the second (standart)? Where can I find a proof? In the Munkres book I have found that Munkres definition implies the standart, but I need to see why the standart would imply the Munkres one.

Comment: We have no idea what the author is using. Munkres only works for manifolds sitting in $\Bbb R^n$. The Whitney embedding theorem says every (abstract) manifold can be embedded, but one doesn’t usually want to cloud the issue with that.

Comment: Again, I have added a little more context using the author's words to not to take all risks of saying something wrong. About what you have said, That's cool! I have heard this theorem before, but It hadn't any context =) You can elaborate an answer to it. Just summarizing what we have discussed and saying the name of the theorem you know for saying when one is equal to another is enough, whenever you know a name, of course. That give me a releaf because I am such a Munkres definition believer but not so much in others.

Comment: they are all basically the same thing. For any $C^1$ submanifold there is an smooth differentiable structure compatible with the $C^1$. The easier approach is to work with smooth manifolds rather than analytic manifolds